# Some questions about absolute value on number fields.

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Assume $K$ is a finite extension of $Q$, and $|\cdot|_v$ is an absolute value. Some questions still puzzle me.

(1) If $|\cdot|v$ is non-archimedean, then we know that $|\mathbb Z|_v\leq 1$. Let $y\in \mathcal O_K$, how to prove that $|y|_v\leq 1$?

(2) For any absolute value $|\cdot|_v$, and any $x\in K$, can we prove that all Galois conjugations of $x$ contained in $K$ must have the same absolute value as $x$? Can you prove it without using further knowledge of places but only using basic Galois theory?

Thank you!

Comment: For 1, write $(y)$ as a product of prime ideals. If $\mathfrak p_v$ is the prime corresponding to $v$, the valuation of $y$ is just the power of $\mathfrak p_v$ appearing in this factorisation. 2 is false. For example, in $\mathbb Q(i)$, take $v = (1 + 2i)$. Then $|1+2i|_v<1$ while $|1-2i|_v = 1$. Or even consider the real absolute value on $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$. Then $|1 + \sqrt 2|\ne |1-\sqrt 2|$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Thank you for your answer, but for 1, the book I read use the conclusion of 1 to prove every non-archimedean valuation is equivalent to a valuation given by a prime ideal. So.. could you give another prove without using "there is a prime corresponding to $v$"? Thank you!

Comment: OK: since $y\in \mathcal O_K$, we have $f(y) = 0$, where $f(X) = X^n + a_{n-1}X^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0$ is a monic polynomial in $\mathbb Z[X]$. Recall that if $|a| < |b|$, then $|a + b| = |b|$. If $|y|>1$, then $|-a_0| = |y^n + \cdots + a_1y|  > 1$, a contradiction.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Thank you!